# Scrollable image in userform

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a word doc with a bunch of ActiveX Control buttons or whatever on it, and each time a button is clicked, a corresponding image needs to be displayed in a popup box.

I have a userform called ImageForm, and this is what I'm doing right now:

```
Sub Button_Clicked()
    ImageForm.Picture = LoadPicture("appropriate_image_path")
    ImageForm.Show
End Sub
```

Each of these images has a width of 8.5 inches, but their heights can vary anywhere from like 3 to 20 inches (they're snippets of a pdf). So I've set the width of the userform to a little more than 8.5 inches, and that looks fine. But I need to be able to scroll vertically through the image in the userform, since some of the images could be taller than a user's monitor.

I'm completely stuck on this. What I've tried so far is adding a frame to the form, then adding an image control inside the form, and setting the "ScrollBars" property of the frame to vertical. Then instead of using "ImageForm.Picture = ..." I use "ImageForm.ImageControl.Picture = ..." But it doesn't work.

Any insight here would be greatly appreciated. Hopefully this question is clear enough, I've only been using VBA for a month or so now. (I miss Java so, so much)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a neat little trick based on one of my [posts](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?511916-VBA-Working-with-Scroll-Bars-The-most-simplest-way)

The idea is to ensure that the image control is in frame control and the image control doesn't have a border. Also the image control's `PictureSizeMode` is set to `fmPictureSizeModeClip` so that we can scroll the image

**SNAPSHOT (DESIGN TIME)**

[image]

**SNAPSHOT (RUN TIME)**

[image]

**CODE**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Frame1
        '~~> This will create a vertical scrollbar
        .ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical

        '~~> Change the values of 2 as Per your requirements
        .ScrollHeight = .InsideHeight * 2
        .ScrollWidth = .InsideWidth * 9
    End With

    With Image1
        .Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg")
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
        .PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeClip
    End With
End Sub
```